# Shouldn't kubernetes default-scheduler respect a node having reached --max-pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I am experiencing that pods are scheduled to nodes which have reached their `--max-pods`. The pods fail with status OutOfpods. There is a lot of other nodes available, which have space for more pods.

Has anyone experienced that pods get scheduled like that?

I tried reading the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#enforcing-node-allocatable) for `--enforce-node-allocatable`, but it really isen't that clear. I noticed that our kubelets are running with `--enforce-node-allocatable=""`, does that have any influence on this?

Comment: Have you use the affinity in this pod? Because Kubernetes default-scheduler must spawn pod on any node which have enough resources and not  contradicts    affinity rules.

Comment: What version of k8s are you using?